# scrartcl chapters Roman numbering and Appendix different

Tags: tables, numbering, koma-script

I would like to have the following structure in `scrartcl`:

I. Introduction

II. Main part

III. Conclusion

Table 1

Table 2

[...]

Appendix:

A.1 Additional Stuff

Table A.1 Additional Stuff Table

A.2 More Stuff

Table A.2 More Stuff Table

Or as an alternative Appendix:

A.1 Additional Stuff

Table A.1.1 Additional Stuff Table #1

Table A.1.2 Additional Stuff Table #2

Is it possible?

Here is how my code looks (working example):

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=10pt, doublespacing, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}                    
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,format=plain,parindent=1em]{caption}
\usepackage{underscore} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\section{Main part}

\appendix

\section{Additional Stuff}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{More Stuff}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Can this be done in `scrartcl`? I tried some stuff, but it always changes the whole document instead of only parts of it.

Comment: `scrartcl` doesn't have `\chapter`.

Comment: No need to load `caption`. KOMA-script has everything you need to customize your captions the way you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed every package not related to the question. The following can be used to achieve your numbering:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=10pt, doublespacing, numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}

\newcommand*\myappendixchanges{%
  \setcounter{table}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{A.\arabic{section}}%
  \gdef\thetable{A.\arabic{table}}}

\gdef\thesection{\Roman{section}.}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\section{Main part}

\appendix
\myappendixchanges

\section{Additional Stuff}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\section{More Stuff}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption XY}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]